# How to use jQuery installed from NuGet Package Visual Studio 2019

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like to ask you how to use jQuery installed from NuGet package in VS 2019.
From an unknow reason nothing added/copied in `~/wwwroot/js` what you can see in the link below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8qUG.png)

Comment: JQuery get copied to the `/Scripts` folder when you install with NUGET, not the `/js` folder that you are looking in.

Comment: It's recommended now to use client-side package manager like NPM or LibMan for client-side libraries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1. NuGet Manager will be responsible for getting code libraries.